# Bound for the norm of expectation of positive semi-definite operators composition

Tags: linear-algebra, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds, positive-semidefinite

Let $\mathcal X: \mathbb R^{m\times n}\to \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ be a random positive semi-definite operator such that $\|\mathcal X\|\leq a$ where $\|\mathcal X\| = \max_A \|\mathcal X(A)\|_F/\|A\|_F$ is the spectral norm, and $a$ is some deterministic constant.
My question is whether the following inequality holds:
$$
\|E[\mathcal X^2]\| \leq \|E[\|\mathcal X\| \cdot \mathcal X]\| \leq a\cdot\|E[\mathcal X] \|.
$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, it is immediate that $\|E[\mathcal X^2]\| \leq E[\|\mathcal X\|\|\mathcal X\|] \leq a E[\|\mathcal X\|]$. However, this is weaker than the desired inequality.

In a way, my question is if the scalar inequality $x\cdot y \leq x\cdot \max(y)$ for $x\geq 0$ generalizes, in some sense, to the positive semi-definite matrix case?

Comment: What are the underlying spaces? Your statement is true for symmetric matrices and the spectral norm

Comment: @md5 Sorry, I now specified the underlying spaces. Does it also hold for positive operators and the spectral norm (as defined in the question)? In addition, could you please hint for the proof? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true. The given conditions imply that $\mathcal X^2\preceq\|\mathcal X\|\mathcal X\preceq a\mathcal X$ in positive semidefinite partial ordering. Hence $E(\mathcal X^2)\preceq E(\|\mathcal X\|\mathcal X)\preceq E(a\mathcal X)$ and in turn, $\|E(\mathcal X^2)\|\le\big\|E\big(\|\mathcal X\|\mathcal X\big)\big\|\le\|E(a\mathcal X)\|$.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to prove that for any distribution on positive semidefinite matrices $A$,

$$\lVert \mathsf{E} A^2\rVert\le \left\lVert \mathsf{E}\left[\lVert A\rVert A\right]\right\rVert,$$

where $\lVert\cdot \rVert$ is the spectral norm.

---

Fix some positive semidefinite matrix $A$. Let $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. Then, for all $x=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i u_i$,

$$\langle x,A x\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 \lambda_i$$

and since $0\le \lambda_i\le \lVert A\rVert$,

$$\langle x,A^2 x\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 \lambda_i^2\le \lVert A\rVert \langle x, Ax\rangle.$$

---

By linearity of expectation, it follows that

$$\langle x, (\mathsf{E} A^2) x\rangle=\mathsf{E} \langle x, A^2x\rangle\le \mathsf{E}\left[\lVert A\rVert \langle x, Ax\rangle\right]=\langle x, \mathsf{E} \left[\lVert A\rVert A\right] x\rangle.$$

And the result follows by taking the supremum over $x$.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the other answer as it refers to operators.

Comment: (It's literally the same proof.)